# Scrollbars not showing

Tags: mono, gtk, scrollbar, gtk#

I have an Image Widget inside of a ScrolledWindow widget.
The image's `Show Scrollbars` Property is checked, and still, when I launch the application, the scrollbars are not shown.

More info:
The image is indeed bigger then the form.
ScrolledWindow's scrollbars policy is always.

What can I do?

Comment: its hard to tell without seeing some of the generated code, I guess this is using MonoDevelop and the stetic gui tool?

Comment: I've just made a very simple gtk# project and this works for me in 2.12.10 using MD 2.6beta3. What type of widget contains your scrolled window?

Comment: can you post (some) of the content of the generated c# file for this from the gtk-gui folder?

Comment: I'll upload the code to pastebin and post here. the scrolled window is contained inside a H-Pane

Comment: @IanNorton http://pastebin.com/020UT1FS

Comment: I can't see any scrollwindows in there.

Comment: @IanNorton: Yeah, I think it was just a human error of mine, sorry for all the trouble :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't what happened, I rebuilt the GUI and it worked.
I'm afraid to touch it :D.

Thank you to all who tried to help me.